# Generate triplets from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to generate all triplets of data from a Pandas dataframe based on a class or label. Say I have a dataframe with a unique identifier for each row, and a class/label for each row. I want triplets where the first two elements are from the same class/label, and the last element is from a different class/label. I am trying to get *all* such triplets.

I can generate the combinations of elements with the *same* label just fine, but when I try to extend these with the elements that have *different* labels, I get an array filled with `None`.

My example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'uuid': np.arange(5),
                   'label': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
print(df)

   label  uuid
0      0     0
1      1     1
2      1     2
3      0     3
4      0     4
```

Note the `uuid` column is just a placeholder here. Point is that it's unique for each row. The following generates all combinations of *same* elements and plugs them into a list:

```
import itertools as it

labels = df.label.unique()
all_combos = []
for l in labels:
    combos = list(it.combinations(df.loc[df.label == l].as_matrix(), 2))
    all_combos.extend([list(c) for c in combos])  # convert to list because I anticipate needing to add to each combo later
all_combos

[[array([0, 0]), array([0, 3])],
 [array([0, 0]), array([0, 4])],
 [array([0, 3]), array([0, 4])],
 [array([1, 1]), array([1, 2])]]
```

Now I want all of these combinations with each *different* element appended.

### I try:

```
for l in labels:
    combos = list(it.combinations(df.loc[df.label == l].as_matrix(), 2))
    combo_list = [list(c) for c in combos]
    for c in combo_list:
        new_combos = [list(c).extend(s) for s in df.loc[df.label != l].as_matrix()]
        all_combos.append(new_combos)
```

### I expect:

```
all_combos

[[array([0, 0]), array([0, 3]), array([1, 1])],
 [array([0, 0]), array([0, 3]), array([1, 2])],
 [array([0, 0]), array([0, 4]), array([1, 1])],
 [array([0, 0]), array([0, 4]), array([1, 2])],
 [array([0, 3]), array([0, 4]), array([1, 1])],
 [array([0, 3]), array([0, 4]), array([1, 2])],
 [array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([0, 0])],
 [array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([0, 3])],
 [array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([0, 4])]]
```

### I get:

```
all_combos

[[None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None, None]]
```

which seems really odd: they aren't even all the same length! But I do have the same number of `None`'s in my result as the expected number of valid triplets.

I also tried `all_combos.extend(new_combos)` and got a 1-D list of 9 elements, so just a flattened version of the result above. In fact any combination of `list.extend` and `list.append` in the last two lines of the inner loop give me either the result shown above, or a flattened version of that result, neither of which makes sense to me.

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comments, `list.extend` and `list.append` are in-place operations, so they wouldn't return anything. How then do I get my list comprehension to give me these values? Or refactor to something else that works?

Comment: `extend` returns `None`, as it is an in-place operation

Comment: @user3483203 that makes sense. Any idea how to get the value I am looking for in that list comprehension then?

Comment: I'd have to look at it more, but why not just use `list(c) + s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I will leave it here in case anybody else runs into a similar issue, but as mentioned in the comments, the issue is that `list.append` and `list.extend` are in-place operations and so return `None`, even inside of a list comprehension.

I was able to get around this issue by using `np.concatenate` to mash my arrays together:

```
for l in labels:
    combos = list(it.combinations(df.loc[df.label == l].as_matrix(), 2))
    for c in combos:
        new_combos = [np.concatenate((c, (s,)), axis=0) for s in df.loc[df.label != l].as_matrix()]
        all_combos.extend(new_combos)
```

Also, `np.append(c, (s,), axis=0)` inside the list comprehension works too.